# SQL Reset variable value by looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query:

```
Declare @variable int
Set @variable = 10
select @variable = case
                        when max(max_val) >= @variable then @variable
                        else max(max_val)
                    end
from dsa_finaldataset
where account_id = 'a1'
and product_id = 'p1'
and product = 'x1'

select * from
(select *, row_number () over (partition by account_id, product_id,product order by revenue desc) as rk from
(select * from test_data
where account_id = 'a1'
and product_id = 'p1'
and product = 'x1'
and @variable between min_val and max_val)x)y
where y.rk =1;
```

Here I am declaring a variable with a value set to it and based on one of the column values (max_val) I either retain the declared value or assign the value of max_val column to the variable. The records matching the criteria will be the query output. My questions on this:

I have about 5 different products with different min_val and max_val for each product. However, the variable entered will be the same and the same condition holds in case of each product. Is there anyway I can use a looping structure where I can get output for all 5 products x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 in the same query such that upon evaluation of variable condition and query execution, the variable is reassigned its original value, after which the condition will be checked and query run again for the next product?

Answer (score 0):

from what I can understand you can wrap the above code within a function with product being a parameter (or maybe all - account_id, product_id and product), and use [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) operator on this function to get data for all your products:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_doCalculations (@account_id VARCHAR(10), @product_id VARCHAR(10), @product VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS @return TABLE (
        /* declare columns needed here */ 
    )
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @variable int
    Set @variable = 10
    select @variable = case
                            when max(max_val) >= @variable then @variable
                            else max(max_val)
                        end
    from dsa_finaldataset
    where account_id = @account_id
    and product_id = @product_id
    and product = @product

    INSERT INTO @return (/* declared columns here */)
    select * 
    from 
    (   select *, row_number () over (partition by account_id, product_id,product order by revenue desc) as rk 
        from    (   select * 
                    from test_data
                    where account_id = @account_id
                        and product_id = @product_id
                        and product = @product
                        and @variable between min_val and max_val) x
                ) y
    where y.rk =1;

    RETURN
END
```

After creating the function, you can query it like this to get the results for all your products (or just the ones you need):

```
SELECT *
FROM    dbo.your_products_table P
        OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_doCalculations(P.account_id, P.product_id, P.product)
WHERE   P.product_id IN ('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5')
```

This will apply your code (function) to the products you need.

Comment: While creating the function, I am getting an error saying "A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context." This error is for the RETURN just fore the END statement. Removing @return the result is not being filtered and I am getting records for all account ids.

Comment: Just edited the script above, it's just RETURN, not RETURN @return.

Comment: Removing @return the data is not getting filtered based on the account_id. When I'm using the second query to pull the result, I am getting all the account_ids. 
Just to clarify, the result should be filtered based on my inputs which would be account_id, product_id, product and variable value

Comment: I`m not sure I understand exactly - but you are are free to APPLY the function with the parameters you want, as well as adding more conditions to the WHERE clause there. If this is not helping, please detail a bit better what is the problem exactly.

Comment: I think I need to go back to the basics of user defined functions once and then try your solution. Thanks for your help!! Will get back to you soon